# Change CPU count for RUNNING Slurm Jobs

Tags: linux, centos, hpc, slurm

I have a SLURM cluster and a RUNNING job where I have requested 60 threads by

```
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=60
```

(I am sharing threads on a node using cgroups)

I now want to reduce the amount of threads to 30.

```
$ scontrol update jobid=274332 NumCPUs=30
Job is no longer pending execution for job 274332
```

The job has still 60 threads allocated.

```
$ scontrol show job 274332
JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=60 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=60 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
```

How would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current version of Slurm, `scontrol` only allows to reduce the number of nodes allocated to a running job, but not the number of CPUs (or the memory).

The [FAQ](https://slurm.schedmd.com/faq.html#job_size) says:

> Use the scontrol command to change a job's size either by specifying a **new node count (NumNodes=)** for the job or identify the **specific nodes (NodeList=)** that you want the job to retain.

(Emphasis mine)